# How to override existing values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a following situation

table1

```
PricelistID  ValidTo    Currency Markup
1            2013-12-31 USD      1.2
2            2013-12-31 USD      1.25  
3            2013-12-31 USD      1.3
4            2013-12-31 USD      1.1
```

table2

```
PricelistID PeriodID Price
1           1        10.00
1           2        20.00
2           3        15.00
3           4        50.00
4           5        30.00
```

Now I have a situation where I need to add new pricelist with values(2013-12-31, USD, 1.5) (only in in table 1) that would  inherit values of pricelistID 4 in table 2, how can I do it?

Query should return

```
PricelistiD ValidTo    Currency Markup PeriodID Price
5           2013-12-31 USD      1.5    5        30.00
```

Comment: Sql 2005, just need to select them

Comment: Are you auggesting that you want to automatically insert a row into table2 when you insert into table1? What would be the logic that would be used to determine WHAT to insert into table2?

Comment: no, i just want to store a new pricelistID that would override markup for existing pricelist but keep the same prices

Comment: I am sorry but I am still struggling to understand what you are trying to make happen here. You say you want to "inherit" the values of pricelist 4 but what is the relationship between the values that you are inserting and the row with PricelistID = 4? If you insert the values you mention into table1, you will be given a PricelistID = 5.  Where does the PricelistID of 4 come into play here?  I think that you are missing something from your explanation of the question.